# Time-efficient clock-wise array rotation in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I'm doing [Hackerearth's](https://hackerearth.com/) challenges, and the very first one is a simple clockwise array rotation. So, given an array such as:

```
arr = "1 2 3 4 5"
```

If you rotate it (clock-wise) for let's say 2 steps then you'd have the following:

```
arr = "4 5 1 2 3"
```

So I was able to built an algorithm that does this, and I also used Julias' native **circshift** function, but I'm still not time-efficient enough. The maximum time allowed per test is 1 second, and my current implementation takes 1.5sec.

My code is the following:

```
test_cases = readline() #read the amount of test cases
tests = test_cases[1:end]
tests = string(tests)
tests = parse(Int8, tests)
for i in 1:tests
    second_line = readline() #reads the size of the array and the steps
    third_line = readline() #read the actual array
    
    function solution(second_line, third_line)
        #first we separate the number of the array from the steps to rotate
        len_steps = split(second_line, " ")
        len = parse(Int8, len_steps[1])
        steps = parse(Int8, len_steps[2])
        
        #secondly we separate the third line into the actual array
        line = split(third_line, " ")
        
        #if steps > length, get the modulus. Else, do the normal stepping.
        if steps > len
            steps = steps%len
        end
        
        #now we start filling out the new array. This is not as effective.
        return join(vcat(line[(len-steps+1):end], line[1:(len-steps)]), " ")
    end
    test = solution(second_line, third_line)
    print(test)
    println(" ")
end
```

This is the current version of the algorithm, and it uses some of Julias' native tools. My previous interpretation had a for loop which just made it worse. As I mentioned, **circshift** doesn't cut it either, so how could I improve it to make it more efficient?

Below I share a sample of the input, but the full file is on [pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/hwYhCP4C)

```
13
384 886
655497 374005 129593 387055 595396 152862 251289 702661 595772 811057 321410 686329 174533 17836 235740 330576 568552 472246 881591 761168 161847 121659 617522 747110 345962 187723 773947 850345 578189 611862 78672 844128 596309 716697 333193 293716 480001 584482 606819 177783 107991 30239 474554 790957 556508 710294 731975 227070 792983 715576 598681 56840 837236 318213 414392 793640 505936 798781 745995 186135 512654 824667 640706 719405 253816 75909 623563 733817 270834 840825 522042 378825 871064 98607 780224 140024 419343 614210 875527 822768 431796 576218 879608 879474 504873 396011 775124 112819 296802 623130 807386 419898 160249 550102 749746 414066 236454 475319 758325 117730 418154 382378 106997 1671 91427 887222 650127 121212 603442 238106 45991 645680 424766 536041 627165 31649 542494 504299 652900 449739 737871 562297 869637 131 722841 331835 24639 569737 417597 393406 687467 446193 386226 794465 58306 477653 394139 708434 209308 99591 556982 255299 355713 83759 791340 84888 115408 435845 199630 768309 496026 547943 43058 78115 158516 376341 409951 183155 48089 827548 187004 345998 375751 573230 242473 44500 152894 247054 752934 870634 855077 411926 227943 312801 106127 629725 397689 221536 676012 207761 600287 274048 755705 253787 352164 16231 630128 762115 707819 678217 302115 894823 634658 288308 570063 877131 332808 333399 226196 696184 306043 183283 718553 144428 106526 824680 774154 114658 656658 162618 322419 867387 436667 688566 223184 399273 315240 853313 771830 125069 243982 175955 630334 878640 74705 810839 468224 17956 246249 304862 324582 162734 98587 653577 815595 205114 580268 302201 319772 847368 464819 252633 816766 511928 43210 650392 13211 358450 605715 785041 93961 460140 571438 724295 440790 256586 637144 519456 274542 493835 824318 209566 267012 533348 863144 184617 738462 155864 97260 668676 105242 562079 23319 532450 176018 574961 284853 697661 35421 501010 584713 637814 63160 766593 464119 503951 125189 711706 633849 10173 815983 560178 219740 185005 195536 693326 878054 544440 849190 77324 315126 56442 249846 846877 199335 36306 523849 484188 733967 169712 87208 31132 417969 150369 797726 492530 264762 533357 306246 621 153973 732672 171241 882145 528119 875209 677481 508184 521659 628681 195950 447227 295565 56238 6557 494900 92544 140848 589530 436954 818992 676739 468086 338971 437550 876254 831502 702312 511622 748190 313375 665595 582872 95059 649750 213002 72278 39683 331628 204380 668364 138020 262049 574371 194259 268606 171282 795235 409454 371254 334199 838889 150003 802286 279870 197995 780550 213382 510749 4624 63583 824125 280661 256897
```

Comment: Put your method definition (`function solution ...`) before the for loop. I don't think this would save time, in fact I'm pretty sure the method isn't actually redefined per iteration. It's just that dynamically redefining methods in if-statements and for-loops makes some crucial optimizations impossible, so it isn't supported in Julia and can cause odd bugs. AFAIK all attempts just wanted to conditionally select methods, and there are alternative ways to do it. Sources: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602, https://discourse.julialang.org/t/redefining-functions-inside-loops/22772

Comment: Can you give more details about how the time is measured? "The maximum time allowed per test is 1 second" what consitutes one test? Is it just one rotation of one array - in which case 1.5 seconds sounds unbelievably excessive. How are they/you  measuring the time? Does it include the compilation time for the code too? It seems likely that what's actually taking time is the I/O, parsing the input and printing the output, more than the shifting itself. But if you could answer the above questions and include some sample inputs in the question too, we could verify the actual source of the issue.

Comment: I suggest that you read the performance tips section of the manual. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ You are breaking some the major guidelines. Put your loop inside a function. Avoid global variables. And why is your function definition _inside_ the loop? It is also critical to do the benchmarking correctly. Use the package BenchmarkTools.jl, and read its manual to use it correctly.

Comment: @SundarR the first input is a variable "T" which represents how many tests are going to be executed. At each test, they give you a new array which can have from 1 to 10^5 elements, and the rotation which can be from 0 steps to 10^6 steps. The time I mentioned (1.5sec) is the time it takes to run all the "T" tests under those conditions. At each test you need to read the input again. I'll added an example of the inputs after the original question.

Comment: If your goal is to test circular shifts, you shouldn't mix this in with file reading and text parsing. Just generate the arrays directly in memory. Also, you should definitely create a minimal working example (MWE) that we can just copy and paste to try for ourselves. Your description of your general approach is not at all detailed enough, and still difficult to follow. Just make an MWE.

Comment: Nothing to do with the current conversation, just an extra clarification about my earlier warning about methods in if statements and for loops. The second link illustrates a bug if you try to replace a method dynamically; only the last method in the loop is compiled for all iterations. However, I should point out it's perfectly fine to define 1 method inside a loop just to capture loop variables; this is a closure and is compiled much like a functor (see Julia docs), where only 1 real method is actually compiled and the different "methods" per iteration are actually callable struct instances.

Comment: @BatWannaBe As far as I can tell, no loop variables are captured in the function definition, so it can just be moved out of the loop. I don't know if it makes a practical difference, but it is un-idiomatic and confusing the way it is currently.

Comment: @DNF Absolutely right, the `solution` method being in the loop does nothing in this case, and keeping methods at top level is idiomatic precisely because of how compilation works. Defining methods in loops and if-statements is a style of coding sometimes found in relatively more dynamic languages that don't compile and optimize, so I felt it was worth explaining why to avoid it in Julia besides functor-based closures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ShiftedArrays`:

```
using ShiftedArrays, BenchmarkTools
a=collect(1:10_000_000)
```

And now:

```
julia> CircShiftedVector(a, 3)
10000000-element CircShiftedVector{Int64, Vector{Int64}}:
  9999998
  9999999
 10000000
        1
        2
        3
        ⋮
  9999995
  9999996
  9999997
```

This is non-allocating so the time cost is one nanosecond:

```
julia> @btime CircShiftedVector($a, 3);
  1.300 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

`circshift` is plenty fast, and you should use that.

It is not clear exactly what you want to measure here, but *is* clear that almost 100% of the time in your code is spent on file reading, string parsing and printing, and that is without considering the performance issues that are caused by working in global scope.

So, first of all, you should wrap your code in functions. Performance tip number 1 in the manual (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/) is "Avoid global variables". This hurts performance a lot. Wrap your code in functions, and make sure all variables are passed as input arguments, don't rely on globals.

As for the performance of `circshift`, consider this:

```
1.7.0> using BenchmarkTools

1.7.0> x = rand(1000);

1.7.0> @btime circshift($x, 500);
  552.604 ns (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)  # <- nanoseconds!

1.7.0> @btime join(circshift($x, 500), " ");
  135.700 μs (2013 allocations: 461.98 KiB)  # <- microseconds!
```

Less than 0.5% of the runtime is spent on `circshift`, and then I'm ignoring the part where you read and parse the data from file, which probably takes much, much longer. I'm pretty confident that `circshift` takes up much less than 1/1000th of the time in your code.

In other words, use `circshift`, and then spend your time improving the performance of the other parts of your code (and read the performance tips ;)